# Is there a way to check the API compatibility of my app for lower levels?

Tags: android, api, compatibility

I'm developing an Android app which will target 2.1/2.2 devices, so I have my project set up to use the 2.2 SDK (API level 8), but allow for installation on devices with at least API level 7.

The problem is that during my daily development, I'm not always paying close attention to which API level of the methods/classes/constants that I'm using, which makes it very easy to break code on older devices.  I have got dynamic classloading working, and as much as I dislike having a ton of extra factory classes and interfaces in my project, I'm willing to deal with that solution.  Currently, the only way I have to check an older API level is to set my project's settings to the given level, rebuild, see what breaks, and then refactor.  It's quite a pain.

What I would really like is the ability to scan my code and check compatibility for a given API level without changing my global project build settings.  Is there some easy way to do this?

Comment: Your process is the same process I'm using.  I've looked for a better option but haven't found one.  I really wish the Eclipse plugin had the option of highlighting anything in your project that isn't available in the minSdkVersion you are targeting.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid to hear that.  For the record, I'm using IntelliJ 9, not eclipse.

Comment: there is no static analysis tool, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on my research and the comment by @CommonsWare, there's no static analysis tool or some other easy way to do this.  Shucks.

Answer (score 2):

Android API Analysis Plug-In for Eclipse:

http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/apianalysis/